# App Tracking Transparency How does effect apps showing ads? - IDFA iOS14

Tags: ios, swift, ads, ios14, idfa

The recent WWDC state that about iOS 14:

> With iOS 14, iPadOS 14, and tvOS 14, you will need to receive the
> user’s permission through the AppTrackingTransparency framework to
> track them or access their device’s advertising identifier. Tracking
> refers to the act of linking user or device data collected from your
> app with user or device data collected from other companies’ apps,
> websites, or offline properties for targeted advertising or advertising

Reference: [User Privacy and Data Use](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/user-privacy-and-data-use/)

As per this guidelines, We need to ask the user for tracking permission using `ATTrackingManager` ([AppTrackingTransparency](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apptrackingtransparency))  framework.

I have a few apps on AppStore, Which is using `Google AdMob` & `FBAudienceNetwork` to deliver ads to the user.

### Question:

1. What's happen if I don't upgrade these apps as per the last WWDC guidelines? Is app continue ads serving to the user?
2. What's happening if User doesn't give tracking permission to the app?
3. App update does make any impact on revenue from ads?

Try to answer this question respected to ads serving, revenue and impact of `App Tracking Transparency`

### Below are all references which I had referred already.

[User Privacy and Data Use](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/user-privacy-and-data-use/)

[App Tracking Transparency](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apptrackingtransparency)

[Google AdMob](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/9997589?hl=en-GB)

[Google AdMob : Implementation](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/ios14)

[AdSupport](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/adsupport)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The firstly, i want to talk about the **IDFA**:

> The Identity for Advertisers (IDFA) is the individual and random identifier used by Apple to identify and measure iOS user devices.

**Bellow IOS14**, Every AdNetworks use **IDFA** for defund a specific user, then They use **IDFA** to be used to deliver personalized ads to user. so **IDFA** help the AdNetworks can show related ads to our users.

**In IOS 14**, the IDFA is hidden and you and adnetwork can't get this IDFA, You must to ask user to allow tracking permission to continue use IDFA in IOS 14 system.

So my answers are:

> Question 1: What's happen if I don't upgrade these apps as per the last WWDC guidelines? Is app continue ads serving to the user?

The short answers is **YES**, Your app still continue ads serving to the user. **BUTTTTTT**: the Adnetwork will do not know anythings about your user, **so all ads will be random and unrelated ads**

->  clickRate will be reduced -> eCPM will be reduced -> **Your revenue will be down too.**

> Question 2: What's happen if User doesn't give tracking permission to the app?

Like the my answer 1  when user don't allow tracking permission, you can't get **IDFA** then **Your revenue will be down again.**.

But in this case, Apple created an another choose for Us and Networks. that is [SKAdNetwork](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skadnetwork) which helps advertisers measure the success of ad campaigns while maintaining user privacy. But Nobody can make sure this API will better current **IDFA** System can make. So you should enable **SKAdNetwork** to track conversions in tracking don't allow case. To get maximum profit

> Question 3: App update does make any impact on revenue from ads?

If your user allow the tracking permission, everything is OKAY like nothing happen.  If not, you have the SKAdNetwork and let pray for SKAdNetwork will work nice like The Apple said.

> Question 4: What is Funding Choices?

[Funding Choices](https://support.google.com/fundingchoices/answer/9180084://) is the Google'Tool to help you to ask user allow tracking permission.  **Funding Choices** and [SDK UMP](https://developers.google.com/ad-manager/mobile-ads-sdk/ios/quick-start) will create the explainer message alert which will automatically be shown immediately before the "Tracking permission" alert.
This is automatically and simple. If you don't like Funding Choices, you can create your explainer message yourself to ask user before the "tracking permission" alert is shown

This is all my knowledges after 3 days researching and working about IDFA, IOS14.....

I hope them can help you something. If i had any mistake, reply here!!!. Thanks

Comment: How to enable SKAdNetwork? Is it enabled by default (e.g. it will happen even if we don't update the app at all)? Does it automatically fallback to it if user rejects AppTrackingTransparency? Thanks

Comment: #1 this is how to enable SKAdNetwork
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skadnetwork
#2 this will be disable if you dont implement them.
#3 this dependent on which adNetwork you use. I use admob and they say Yes, but i need enable SKAdNetWork first. https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/ios14#skadnetwork

Comment: Hi @HiteshSurani, Does accessing UUID affect? NSString *strUUID = [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString];

Comment: @Tritmm please help

Comment: @Harish don't worry! your code will not be affected by them. 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/uuid

"Initializes a new UUID with RFC 4122 version 4 random bytes."
this mean when you call the init function, a random UUID will be return. so UUID is not IDFA/IDFV.
your code will not be affected by any updates. don't worry. Have fun!!

Comment: @Tritmm: Thank you for your time to respond.

Comment: ATT popup is not mandatory now, required to obtain permission starting early next year.
https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=hx9s63c5

Comment: Do we load and show ad even if user says do not allow tracking?

Comment: @atalayasa your question is "Question 2"

Comment: I have enabled SKAdNetwork and implemented requestIDFA() method as google suggested Now my app is pushed to the app store without any problem. But my app is not receiving ads when the user disagrees to allow tracking.. Anyway I'm loading ad in both scenarios

Comment: In what specific case am I forced to use ATT?
If my app just collects user's personal info to register him/her to my service and enable authorized app functionalities, like e-commerce, showing authorized content, showing orders, making checkouts, and so on, is ATT mandatory in this case?

Answer (score 7):

The current version my app (pre-iOS 14) is still showing ads, but ad revenue has HALVED since iOS was released. So yes, it seems ad revenue is impacted if you don't implement App Tracking Transparency (ATT).

I have updated my app WITHOUT ATT and Apple now rejects my app. Even though I share no user data with the AdMob framework, disabled location tracking and IAP tracking for AdMob.

So basically my app does not track anything other than the IDFA used by AdMob and Apple rejects it.

My advice would be to implement ATT if you are using Admob. If you don't do that, revenue will decrease and Apple will reject future app updates.

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing your experience.. 
Important Question : We've disabled personalised ads in Admob. But since I also want to track demographic data that is not used anywhere other than for analytics purpose via IDFA , will I still need to implement/show ATT before submitting my App for Apple Review?

Comment: @Mac yes you basically need to implement it for any type of tracking.

Answer (score 3):

No IDFA means no personalized ads. Because all publishers over the years has build whole advertising services based on IDFA/GAID. Without IDFA you advertisers will not be able to run re-targeting campaigns or narrow targeting options to find target user group.

So you will receive less ads, and those you will see will have low CPM value. So your app will be flooded with cheap/poor quality ads.

You can learn more [on my blog article](https://wojtek.ch/advertising/programmatic/how-ios-14-will-change-programmatic-mobile-advertising/)