# Shall iOS14 and UUID be going away?

Tags: ios14

Just wondering if UUID() is going away in iOS14?

It’s just that we use it to serve "now playing" songs information to each user. We provide different playlist to every listener.

Comment: I don't think there was an announcement for the deprecation of UUID, and the documentation doesn't indicate any update. Why do you think it would go away ?

Comment: @Imotep https://www.cnbc.com/amp/2020/08/26/facebook-apple-ios-14-could-cut-audience-network-revenue-in-half.html

Comment: That's the IDFA you access using the AdSupport framework, that's a different thing from the UUID.

Comment: Have a look at this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63499520/app-tracking-transparency-how-does-effect-my-exsting-app-idfa-ios14)