# How to request App Tracking Transparency authorization in Flutter for Admob Native Ads displayed on IOS 14?

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, admob

> With iOS 14, iPadOS 14, and tvOS 14, you will need to receive the
> user’s permission through the AppTrackingTransparency framework to
> track them or access their device’s advertising identifier. Tracking
> refers to the act of linking user or device data collected from your
> app with user or device data collected from other companies’ apps,
> websites, or offline properties for targeted advertising or
> advertising

How to request App Tracking Transparency authorization in Flutter for Admob Native Ads displayed on IOS 14?
Will the app continue ads serving to the user if a user doesn't accept it?

Answer (score 2):

I use [admob_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/admob_flutter) which allows you to do that by calling `await Admob.requestTrackingAuthorization()`

If user doesn't accept then the app will continue to serve non-personalized ads. For more details check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63522856/1444748)

Answer (score 1):

You can user [app_tracking_transparency](https://pub.dev/packages/app_tracking_transparency) library to achieve what you want if you don't use `admob_flutter` library.

Readme file of the library explains all the setup proccess and you can request ATT popup like:

```
await AppTrackingTransparency.requestTrackingAuthorization()
```